# _store_result() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request' in celery

Tags: django, celery

I have no idea why celery suddenly stopped working, probably missing some settings but I don't think so .... and code of views that runs celery tasks is the same, sentry only shows as follows:

[image]

It works locally (develop env) but in production it doesn't, I'm using django 1.4.2, djcelery 3.0.11 and celery 3.1.9, what do you think happening?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem, but but part of an upgrade (among others):

- Django >=1.5,<1.6 -> >=1.6,<1.7
- celery <3.1 -> >=3.1.17
- django-celery <3.1 -> <=3.1.16

I can see you [opened an issue on Celery's Github project](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2462). However, The `request` keyword argument [was added to celery a long time ago](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/9c38139d5bdcfd8173fc7fa6d219d99acc59a577), and it seems to be still present in the master branch.

This is the logic in a base back-end class, but if the implementation you're using doesn't have this keyword argument, it'll crash. In your case, it looks like the versions of celery and django-celery are incompatible.

[The commit](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/commit/374496c36640fe853d5f8acefa952971d87315b8#diff-07ac3142c20036ec08f58749fbd90e18) to bring support to 3.1 is only available in following versions of django-celery: v3.1.16  v3.1.15 v3.1.10 v3.1.9 v3.1.1 v3.1.0, I suggest upgrading to one of these.

Comment: thnks for your advise ... I will try it the next time and if you are right then I will mark this answer as solution.